# Share Variable among instances in cluster weblogic

Tags: ejb, jms, weblogic, cluster-computing

I have one webapp which is running on weblogic from last many years. Now I need to deploy the application on clustered environment. The issue I am facing it that my application publishes JMS messages and after deploying on cluster as there are two instances, there are duplicate messages being published.

I don't want to hardcode any servername or property in file. Is there any way I can have some global variable I can share between managed servers.

What could be best way to solve this kind of issue. Application code is legacy and uses EJBs so changing much of EJB code would be a bit difficult and risky.

Thanks
Sourabh

Comment: are you using some kind of timer/scheduler?